# Kotlin extension function for View.setMargins

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to write a kotlin extension function for view to update the current view margin. I know that for the same you need to make change to view's layoutParams, although I am trying to create a generic method & unable to understand how to pass the parent viewgroup / layout type to handle this.

```
fun <T> View.setMargins(margin:Int){
   var lp = // don't know how to get layout params here
   // how to get RelativeLayout.LayoutParams or ViewGroup.LayoutParams etc..

   // if I do this.layoutParams then I am unable to call setMargins function on that since it is only available for RelativeLayout.LayoutParams / VeiwGroup.LayoutParams etc etc..
}
```

Comment: this.layoutParams ..

Comment: updated answer. try this ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using extension function your **receiver type** will become parameter as `this` inside that block.
So you can use like this way.

```
fun <T> View.setMargins(margin:Int){
    if (this.layoutParams is ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        val params = this.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        params.setMargins(<your_margins>);
    }
}
```

Comment: hii, I should have clarified the question a bit more (update now). I can get the layoutParams using this. or otherwise but it doesn't allow to setMargins on that. For the same I need to use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams / ViewGroup.LayoutParams etc.. I need a generic method so that I can pass them as generic or otherwise and call the function setMargins on them in that way.

Comment: the solution provided is possible although I have to create multiple if else checks for all types of LayoutParams since ViewGroup and other Layouts don't inherit from same parent class. Is it possible in some way or another to create a complete generic class ?

Comment: but i think this is for all layout who supports margin, so i think you don't need to make if and else ...
read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams

Comment: let me try this once and will get back to you :)

Comment: sorry for so late reply, it works as expected. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think [kotlinx](https://android.github.io/android-ktx/core-ktx/androidx.view/android.view.-view-group.-margin-layout-params/set-margins.html) already done that, check it out

Comment: yes but the extension function is on MarginLayoutParams not the View itself